# Why the OK button is not getting displayed in a pop-up in following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, alert

my code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link href="http://localhost/abc/pqr/web/css_new/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://localhost/abc/pqr/web/css_new/scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/abc/pqr/web/css/jquery_ui/ui.all.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/abc/pqr/web/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/abc/pqr/web/js/jquery_ui/ui.core.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/abc/pqr/web/js/jquery_ui/ui.dialog.js"></script>

    <script>
      var timer;
      var keys = {};

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mouseleave(function () {
          customAlert("Your mouse is away");
        });
      });

      $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        keys[e.which] = true;
      });

      $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        delete keys[e.which];
      });

      if( (keys[91] && keys[68]) || (keys[18] && keys[9]) || (keys[17] && keys[91] && keys[68]) ) { 
        customAlert("Your mouse is away");
      }

      function customAlert(customText) {
        $("#popUp").html(customText);
        timer = setInterval(customAlert2, 5000);

        $("#popUp").dialog({
          dialogClass: "no-close",
          buttons: [{
                      text: "OK", click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                    }]
        });
      }

      function customAlert2() {
        location.reload();
        $("#popUp2").dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        buttons: [{
                  text: "OK", click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
                }]
        });
      }      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My first PHP program</h1>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <div id="popUp" title="First alert message"></div>
    <div id="popUp2" title="Second alert message">Time is over</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the pop-up is displayed the Ok button is missing. It's displaying only 'O'.Can you help me in this regard please? I've also attached the screen shot of the popup. Please look at it to get better idea of my issue.[image]

Comment: Your first PHP program has NO PHP in it! haha. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI documentation describes different approach for defining buttons.

An example from official docs:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:140,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Delete all items": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

So, in your case it should look like that:

```
$("#popUp").dialog({
      dialogClass: "no-close",
      buttons: {
          "OK": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              clearInterval(timer);
          }
      }
});

$("#popUp2").dialog({
      dialogClass: "no-close",
      buttons: {
          "OK": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Maris. But I've on issue with the above code. I'm not able to fire the Click event on Ok button as I used to do. You have not defined a click event on the Ok button. How to achieve this thing?

Comment: @PHPLover an anonymous function right after buttons name is the one which gets executed onClick. You should recreate your issue on jsfiddle.net so we can test your code and help fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code on JS fiddle and called your mouseleave function with the custom alert you provided over there and its working fine i.e when i leave the output window it is showing me the dialog box with "OK" button.

Please find this link and write your second fx too, may be we can find something over there.

Please find the jsFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/LtQnT/352/

```
$(document).mouseleave(function () {
           //$( "#popUp" ).dialog( "open" );  
          customAlert('Hi');
        });
```